# Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, laravel, ubuntu, xampp, localhost

I am trying to connect Xampp MySQL with my laravel project. And I still having the following issue

> "Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such
> file or directory (SQL: select * from `md_countries`) "

when I run PHP artisan migrate. I use php7.4, Laravel8, Ubuntu20 terminal and XAMPP updated server. I have already import sql file and my .env file configuration is correct.

Edited:: this is new issue after I run sudo service mysql start.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdcsO.png)

Comment: what does `select version()` as a sql statement show? Can you show the code by editing the question?

Comment: this is new issue after I run sudo service mysql start.  >> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (SQL: select * from `md_countries`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your error screenshot I have seen in your question. Now its connection error. Check you have put correct username,password, dbname and server name.
If you are using mariadb, please try specifying port in servername like localhost:3306 or 127.0.0.1:3306

For Troubleshooting, visit http://localhost/phpmyadmin and check whether your given credentials help you in logging.

Comment: thanks @IamLitto, I just solved my problem.